# Points are collinear and not collinear at the same time

Tags: c++, geometry

Suppose that I have the following chart -- https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eabskyo0hk

I need to do the following:

1. Determine whether apex (endpoint1), dest (newvertex) and endpoint1
   are collinear.
2. If they are not collinear, find their intersection point.

I wrote the following code to do that -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c08cbe113e706a9c

Unfortunately, it doesn't work properly. It says that those points are not collinear but then it says that their intersection point is dest (newvertex) so that invalidates the first statement.

I suppose that this must be due to the floating point-related issues but I wonder how can I fix it w/o changing the coordinates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked value of `(y1 - y2) * (x1 - x3) - (y1 - y3) * (x1 - x2)`?

Comment: @Mbo Yes, it equals to `-0.00006926059722900`

Answer (score 1):

Your coordinate values have very large magnitude, so comparison of cross-product magnitude with `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` gives false result.

Edit: `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` is not suitable as "small value here".

You can try to scale "small value" accordingly to coordinates. Example:

```
my_eps = 1.0E-9;
eps =  my_eps * Max(abs(x1), abs(y1)....
```

Note that small difference of two big values already contains large relative error, so next approach is wrong:

```
eps = my_eps * Max(abs(y1 - y2), abs(x1 - x3), abs(y1 - y3), abs(x1 - x2));
```

Described method should improve result, but won't provide "silver bullet" - there are special computational methods for robust, error-prone intersection calculations (problem is global). [Example - orientation test](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, it doesn't work either -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/456a47873d37cd76

Comment: I've read what is `std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()` - and you'd better to use own constant like 1.0E-9